# Compiling WebRTC Linux ARM on Windows Host

Tags: linux, arm, webrtc, windows-build-tools

I spent 2 days trying to compile WebRTC for Raspbery PI.
I'm on Windows host and there is absolutely zero info in internet how to do this.
Linux WebRTC requires to run sysroot installation script. It just fails on windows due to some tar wrong options.
Somehow I managed to manually run tar though it gave me several hundreds errors regarding some symbolic links creation.

Next error is about some ptoto_library:

ERROR at //build/toolchain/win/BUILD.gn:15:1: Assertion failed.
assert(is_win)
^-----
See //third_party/protobuf/proto_library.gni:413:14: which caused the file to be included.
deps = [ _protoc_label ]

If I disable proto library it fails on compilation because of clang++ is not found.

Is there way to compile WebRTC for Linux from Windows host?
Strange that there is no any info about such possibility at all.

Comment: WebRTC packages are available  https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=WebRTC ........... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=WebRTC ...............  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/34/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/w/

Comment: I didn't find WebRTC native libs among those links. There are some audio-processing libs. And that's it.